# How to animate a gradient progress bar

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I've got a progress bar which I animate using a repeating timer. It works fine, except that the animation isn't quite as smooth as using core animation. If anyone has any suggestions how to implement it using core animation, I'd be grateful! I have no problems using core animation for simpler stuff, but the animated gradient, etc, has stumped me.

My code is here -

```
-(id)initWithWidth:(float)theWidth radius:(float)theRadius progress:(float)theProgress
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, theWidth, theRadius * 2)];
    if (self) {

        _progressBarWidth = theWidth;
        _radius = theRadius;
        _progress = (float)theProgress;

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    }
    return self;
}


-(void)setProgress:(float)theProgress
{
    _progress = theProgress;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}


-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // gradient for blue background (pale blue -> dark blue)

    float colours[] = {0.0, 135.0 / 255.0, 237.0 / 255.0, 1.0, 1.0 / 255.0, 24.0 / 255.0, 140.0 / 255.0, 1.0};

    CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    size_t num_locations = 2;
    CGFloat locations[2] = {0.0, 1.0};
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colours, locations, num_locations);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, _radius, 0.0);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, _progressBarWidth, 0.0, _progressBarWidth, _radius, _radius);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, _progressBarWidth, 2.0 * _radius, _progressBarWidth - _radius, 2.0 * _radius, _radius);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0.0, 2.0 * _radius, 0.0, _radius, _radius);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0.0, 0.0, _radius, 0.0, _radius);

    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextClip(context);

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(_progressBarWidth / 2.0, 0.0);
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(_progressBarWidth / 2.0, 2.0 * _radius);

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);

    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);


    // gradient for progressed element (pale yellow -> dark yellow)

    float colours2[] = {252.0 / 255.0, 224.0 / 255.0, 0.0, 1.0, 246.0 / 255.0, 191.0 / 255.0, 0.0, 1.0};

    baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colours2, locations, num_locations);

    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    // this defines an overall clipping path for the yellow bar (it's got a square end which can protrude when it's near 100%)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, _radius, kDefaultLineWidth);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, _progressBarWidth - kDefaultLineWidth, kDefaultLineWidth, _progressBarWidth - kDefaultLineWidth, _radius, _radius - kDefaultLineWidth);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, _progressBarWidth - kDefaultLineWidth, 2.0 * _radius - kDefaultLineWidth, _progressBarWidth - _radius, 2.0 * _radius - kDefaultLineWidth, _radius - kDefaultLineWidth);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, kDefaultLineWidth, 2.0 * _radius - kDefaultLineWidth, kDefaultLineWidth, _radius, _radius - kDefaultLineWidth);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, kDefaultLineWidth, kDefaultLineWidth, _radius, kDefaultLineWidth, _radius - kDefaultLineWidth);

    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextClip(context);

    // now draw the yellow bar
    float progressWidth = _progress * _progressBarWidth;

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, progressWidth, kDefaultLineWidth);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, kDefaultLineWidth, kDefaultLineWidth, kDefaultLineWidth, _radius, _radius - kDefaultLineWidth);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, kDefaultLineWidth, 2.0 * _radius - kDefaultLineWidth, _radius, 2.0 * _radius - kDefaultLineWidth, _radius - kDefaultLineWidth);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, progressWidth, 2.0 * _radius - kDefaultLineWidth);

    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextClip(context);

    startPoint = CGPointMake(progressWidth / 2.0, kDefaultLineWidth);
    endPoint = CGPointMake(progressWidth / 2.0, 2.0 * _radius - kDefaultLineWidth);

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);

    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);


    // draw the scale

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.25f);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);

    float div = _progressBarWidth / 10;
    for (float i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, div * i, 0.25);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, div * i, _radius * 2.0 + 1.75);

        CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);

    }

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor);

    for (float i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, div * i - 0.5, 0.25);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, div * i - 0.5, _radius * 2.0 + 1.75);

        CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);

    }

}
```

Images of progress bar at 0% & 75%:

[image: Progress bar at 0%]

[image: Progress bar at 75%]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you looked at [CAGradientLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html)? It's made for animating gradients

Answer (score 0):

You must not call drawing code multiple times during animation. 
In your case simplest way is use two views: one for start state and one for final state.
You can add them as subviews to your progress bar view.
Then you draw both views only once (or even use ready images) and animate frames of views.

E.g.

```
...
[self addSubview:endView];
[self addSubview:startView];
...

-(void)animateProgressFrom:(float)fromValue to:(float)toValue
{  
    CGRect startRect = self.bounds;
    startRect.size.width *= fromValue;
    startView.frame = startRect;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        CGRect endRect = self.bounds;
        endRect.size.width *= toValue;
        startView.frame = endRect;
    }];
}
```

And it can be any two images, not necessary gradient color.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately not as simple as that as due to the fairly complex layout of the graphic, as far as I see I can't just "stretch" it or overlay the progress & animate it growing (semi-circular ends, border with its own gradient). I'll try & post a couple of images.

Comment: I've linked to 2 images at the end of the original question.

Comment: Method I've described in my answer above is applicable for your images. It is ok with semicircular ends and gradient borders.
It only not appliable for semi-transparent images.

Comment: Even for semitransparent images it can be easily modified by adding each subview to intermediate superviews with clipsToBound = YES;

Comment: I know what you're saying about adding subviews & animating them, I'm sure I could do it that way. I would just have liked to have been able to find a way to use core animation, especially as I would like to be able to use semi-transparent images too... Thanks for your help anyway - sorry can't mark it as the accepted answer as I'm waiting hopefully for some core animation stuff :-)

Answer (score 0):

I adopted a much simpler approach in the end, layering clipped UIViews & using animateWithDuration:animations:

Here's the main code -

```
-(id)initWithWidth:(float)theWidth radius:(float)theRadius progress:(float)theProgress duration:(float)theDuration
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, theWidth, theRadius * 2)];
    if (self) {

        _progressBarWidth = theWidth;
        _radius = theRadius;
        _progress = (float)theProgress;
        _animationDuration = theDuration;

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        // make the view the right shape

        self.layer.cornerRadius = _radius;
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;

    }
    return self;
}


-(void)showProgress
{

    // draw the main background (which is seen as the outline)

    float tempColours[] = {0.0, 135.0 / 255.0, 237.0 / 255.0, 1.0, 1.0 / 255.0, 24.0 / 255.0, 140.0 / 255.0, 1.0};
    NSMutableArray *colours = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        [colours addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:tempColours[i]]];
    }

    // GradientView is a class which gives me UIViews with a gradient fill

    GradientView *mainBGView = [[[GradientView alloc] initWithWidth:_progressBarWidth height:2.0 * _radius colours:colours] autorelease];
    mainBGView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _progressBarWidth, 2.0 * _radius);
    [self addSubview:mainBGView];


    // add the sub-background and progress bar element

    UIView *clippingContainerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kDefaultLineWidth, kDefaultLineWidth, _progressBarWidth - 2.0 * kDefaultLineWidth, 2.0 * _radius - 2.0 * kDefaultLineWidth)] autorelease];
    clippingContainerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    clippingContainerView.layer.cornerRadius = _radius - kDefaultLineWidth;
    clippingContainerView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    float tempBackgroundColours[] = {152.0 / 255.0, 152.0 / 255.0, 152.0 / 255.0, 1.0, 216.0 / 255.0, 216.0 / 255.0, 216.0 / 255.0, 1.0};
    NSMutableArray *backgroundColours = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        [backgroundColours addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:tempBackgroundColours[i]]];
    }

    GradientView *greyBGView = [[[GradientView alloc] initWithWidth:_progressBarWidth - 2.0 * kDefaultLineWidth height:2.0 * _radius - 2.0 * kDefaultLineWidth colours:backgroundColours] autorelease];
    greyBGView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _progressBarWidth - 2.0 * kDefaultLineWidth, 2.0 * _radius - 2.0 * kDefaultLineWidth);
    [clippingContainerView addSubview:greyBGView];

    float tempProgressBarColours[] = {251.0 / 255.0, 215.0 / 255.0, 17.0 / 255.0, 1.0, 244.0 / 255.0, 184.0 / 255.0, 2.0 / 255.0, 1.0};
    NSMutableArray *progressBarColours = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        [progressBarColours addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:tempProgressBarColours[i]]];
    }

    GradientView *barGradientView = [[[GradientView alloc] initWithWidth:1.0 height:2.0 * _radius - 2.0 * kDefaultLineWidth colours:progressBarColours] autorelease];
    barGradientView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 2.0 * _radius); // start with progress bar too narrow to see
    [clippingContainerView addSubview:barGradientView];

    [self addSubview:clippingContainerView];


    // animate the progress bar

    float progressWidth = _progress * _progressBarWidth; // how wide it is at end of animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:_animationDuration
                     animations:^{
                         barGradientView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, progressWidth, 2.0 * _radius);
                     }];

}
```

Pretty straight forward, & does the job nicely.